# Crear un array dentro de una función y mostrar sus valores desde el main

Tags: c++, array

En *C++* hice una función que dada una longitud, crea un array y lo devuelve. Por último muestro sus valores fuera de la función.

Estuve investigando y dicen que en *C++* no es posible devolver un array, y para esto hay dos alternativas, una es devolver un puntero, y otra es pasarle como parámetro la función a un `void`.

Hice una función que se ejecuta correctamente, pero me tira una advertencia.

```
int* crear_array(int longitud)
{
    int arr[longitud];
    return arr;
}
```

La advertencia es la siguiente:

> warning: address of local variable 'arr' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]

La pregunta es, ¿Qué significa esa advertencia?

Si yo inicializo la variable desde el `main` me tira error.

```
int arr[] = crear_array(10);
```

El error es el siguiente:

> error: initializer fails to determine size of 'arr'
>   error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Esto significa que tampoco puedo inicializarlo como un array, entonces uso un puntero `int*`, que es el mismo tipo que la función `crear_array`.

¿Generalmente cómo se crea un array en *C++*? ¿Tengo que castear el array o crear un puntero a la antigua y hacer `malloc`?

Quizás no sea buena idea crearlo dentro de la función sino en el `main`, pero de poder hacerse, ¿Cómo se haría sin que salgan advertencias?

Este es mi código final:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int* crear_array(int longitud)
{
    int arr[longitud];
    for(int i=0;i<longitud;i++){arr[i]=0;}
    arr[9]=3;
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    int* arr = crear_array(10);
    cout<<arr[8]<<" "<<arr[9]<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La advertencia significa que estas devolviendo el puntero de un array local, pero cuando la función retorna, ese array deja de existir (porque es local a la función).

yo diría que si no queres usar la función **malloc()**, entonces deberías usar el operador **new**.

```
int* crear_array(int longitud)
{
    return new int[longitud];
}
```

ACLARACION: en éste caso obtendrias un array con valores basura, si lo que queres es que crer una función que devuelba un array "limpio", deberias hacer lo siguiente:

```
int* crear_array(int longitud)
{
    int* ret = new int[longitud];
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        ret[i] = 0;
    return ret;
}
```

O usando la función memset para "limpiar" el array:

```
int* crear_array(int longitud)
{
    int* ret = new int[longitud];
    memset(ret, 0, sizeof(int)*longitud);
    return ret;
}
```

Y para eliminar el array usar el operador **delete**...

```
void eliminar_array(int* arr)
{
    delete [] arr;
}
```

Comment: No conocía `memset`, ahora miré [esta referencia](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) y veo que hay que hacer `#include <cstring>`. Comento algo curioso, traté de cambiar el argumento 0 por 1 y al mostrar la posición 0 se ve el número 16843009. No sé por qué ocurrirá eso, pero me sorprendió.

Answer (score 0):

No hay problema usando malloc, para el sistema es mucho mas limpio hacerlo de esa manera.

Recuerda que cuando una funcion finaliza su proceso todas las variables locales son eliminadas y por lo tanto el puntero es inutil por que la variable ha sido limpiada de la memoria, entonces quedas con un puntero que en realidad no apunta a nada, de ahi que el compilador mande solo una advertencia.